# Clickable custom legend angular-chart.js bar chart

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to create custom legend to my bar chart. It's how i try to do it

```
                      generateLabels: function (chart) {
                      if (chart.data.labels.length && chart.data.datasets.length) {
                          return chart.data.labels.map(function (label, i) {
                              var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
                              var ds = chart.data.datasets[0];
                              return {
                                  text: $scope.languagesOfCurrentSiteObject[i].localizedName,
                                  fillStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[i],
                                  hidden: isNaN(chart.data.datasets[0].data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
                                  // Extra data used for toggling the correct item
                                  index: i
                              };
                          });
                      } else {
                          return [];
                      }
                  },
```

It's create well but when i click on some text of my legend to hide clicked data I get such error

> ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_meta' of undefined
>       at 23.module.exports.Chart.Controller.getDatasetMeta

It occurs in them library method

```
        onClick: function(e, legendItem) {
        var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
        var ci = this.chart;
        var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);

        // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
        meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;

        // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
        ci.update();
    },
```

in this line`var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);` beacouse I can only use this method with index == 0.
If i set index = 0 then I get error in the next line couse dataSets also have only one element in the array and then inside elemenet of datas but only with values not propertis like hidden.